# Ordering a list with multiple data types from text file

Tags: python, list, sorting, text-files

As the title says, I'm trying to order a list with multiple data types, i.e. "123 - abc", "20 - xyz", etc..  I've tried sorting it the usual way with .sort() and .sorted() like so:

```
import csv

x = open("leaderboard.txt","r")
reader = csv.reader(x)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
allRows.sort(reverse = True)
print(allRows)
```

but this orders it wrong.

It should be ordered with the numbers in descending order, "123 - xyz" "20 - abc" "10 - xyz", however it orders it as "20 - abc" "123 - xyz" "10 - xyz"

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all strings are holding this format as shown, you could `sort` by using the `int` of `.split(' -')` index `0` as your key

```
lst = [["20 - abc"], ["123 - xyz"], ["10 - xyz"]]
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x[0].split(' -')[0]), reverse=True))
# ['123 - xyz', '20 - abc', '10 - xyz']
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it comes up with: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
are there any other ways of going about this?

Comment: @Dave works make sure your list is formatted properly, try copy and past this entire code over

Comment: the list is formatted the same throughout, unless you mean the actual list itself, in which case, how would I format it?

Comment: @Dave no I meant your list is setup identical to this? with strings seperated by commas? and then you are using the `sorting` expression exactly as is ?

Comment: It's in the text file as shown above, and when retrieved its formatted as

_[['52 - asd'], ['43 - xyz'], ['24 - abc'], ['20 - xyz'], ['2 - abc'], ['123 - asd'], ['10 - abc']]_

Comment: @Dave okay that is why its a list of lists one second

Comment: @Dave change `x.split` to `x[0].split`

Comment: Thanks mate.  Sorry for not noticing it's a list of lists, I'm new to python. :)

Comment: @Dave No prob, been there. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is string sorting. For example, `'100'` will sort before `'2'` (with *ascending* order), as each character is ordered sequentially. You need to provide a `key` argument with a custom function which converts a portion of your string to `int`:

```
L = ["123 - xyz", "20 - abc", "10 - xyz"]

res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), reverse=True)

["123 - xyz", "20 - abc", "10 - xyz"]
```

Comment: Like with Vash's answer, it comes up with an AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on your example in text file "123 - abc", "20 - xyz"

"string" and "integer" values have different hex values, so a string or character "1" (Hex - 223122a) is different to integer 1 (Hex - 31a). You are sorting by string values and they will not treat your numbers as integers and this is why you are getting a strange output.

Comment: That explains why it's messing up, thanks.  Is there a way to still order them, or will I have to change my code completely?